# Как можно увидеть результат выполнения метода `Console.Write("Hello Word")` в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

В стандартных средствах этого я не нашел , может есть какие-то плагины ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Открыть `cmd.exe` и запустить скомпилированное приложение?

Comment: а проще можно как-то ?

Comment: хочу чтобы в стандартной консоли результат отображался

Comment: Если есть желание выводить данные в окно "вывода", то нужно воспользоваться System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Вывод в Output"). Но это не значит, что сообщение появится в консоли

Comment: не работает ваш метод :(

Comment: А если зайти в настройки File -> Preference -> Settings и прописать там `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true`? Хотя из `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` должно работать.

Comment: не работает. просит `Cannot detect required Mono version (5.0.1). Install it from http://www.mono-project.com/download/` поставил, ничего не меняется

Comment: Так ли вам нужно работать в VS Code? Да, VS очень требовательная программа, но почему бы не посмотреть в сторону, например, SharpDevelop? Неплохая альтернатива, если не требуется огромный, но избыточный функционал студии. Аналогично и с MonoDevelop.

Comment: Visual Studio Code поддерживает и множество плагинов

Comment: Не спорю, но автор хочет писать и компилировать C# код, для чего есть готовые решения.